# Scroll page to div onload on vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, vue-component, vuex

I am facing problem scrolling page to a div on page load using vue js.

```
<div v-for="(answer, index) in answers">
    <p>{{answer.id}}</p> <p>{{answer.body}}</p>
</div>
```

how can i scroll page onload to answer having certain id?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs) to each `div` like :

```
<div v-for="(answer, index) in answers" :ref="answer.id">
    <p>{{answer.id}}</p> <p>{{answer.body}}</p>
</div>
```

and in mounted hook add the following code :

```
mounted(){
 this.$refs["4"].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "start"});
  //replace 4 by your preferred id

}
```